# Root path for saved queries in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin

When I save or load a query in pgAdmin4 3.4, the file dialog shows just an empty directory named `/`. I can create folders inside it and I can save the query inside it. But I have no idea where this folder is actually located in my filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

On my kubuntu 18.04 it is `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/`.

For Windows, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849894/1668200

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Kubuntu 18.04 as well) it's:

```
/home/<user>/.pgadmin/storage/<user>
```

I run pgadmin 4 within a python virtual environment as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

On manjaro linux and virtual environment for pgAdmin4 under python3 pip install (see https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/):

let it be that you used admin2586@gmail.com as the initial pgAdmin user account in pgAdmin first start, then you will find your saved .sql files in /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/admin2586_gmail.com/.

edit: this will work even on your ubuntu linux distro (I guess :)) as it relies on a python virtual environment)